# Vector Quantizitation to directional code words

Tags: c++, vector

I need to quantize my vector and generate directional code words from `0 to 15`. So I had implemented following code line using C++ to achieve that. Just pass 2 points and calculate `atan()` value using that points. But it's only return just `0 to 7`. other values are not return. Also sometimes it's return very large numbers like `42345`. How can I modify this to return directional code words from `0 to 15`

```
double angle = abs(atan((acc.y - acc.lastY)/(acc.x - acc.lastX))/(20*3.14159/180));
```

Comment: Not just it's returning only 0 to 7, but due to the `abs` it's returning the values for completely wrong directions.

Comment: You say in the text that you want values 0 to 15, but to get that you need to multiply by `8/PI`, not `180/20*PI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the [`std::atan2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) function is for.

Since *tan* function is periodic over just half circle. Logically, if you negate both coordinates, the expression in the argument comes out the same, so you can't tell the two cases apart. So you have to first look at which quadrant you are in by checking the signs and than adding 180 if you are in the negative half-space. The `std::atan2` function will do it for you.

```
double angle = std::atan2(acc.y - acc.lastY, acc.x - acc.lastX) * (8 / PI);
```

It has the added benefit of actually working when `acc.x == acc.lastX`, while your expression will signal division by zero.

Additionally, the use of `abs` is wrong. If you get angle between *-π* and *π* you want to get angle between 0 and 2*π*, you need to write:

```
double angle = std::atan2(acc.y - acc.lastY, acc.x - acc.lastX); // keep it in radians
if(angle < 0)
    angle += 2 * PI;
return angle * (8 / PI); // convert to <0, 16)
```

With `abs` you are unifying the cases with oposite sign of *y*, but same *x*.

Additionally if you want to round the values so that 0 represents directions along *x* axis slightly off to either side, you'll need to modify the rounding by adding half of the interval width and you'll have to do before normalizing to the ⟨0, 2*π*) range. You'd start with:

```
double angle = std::atan2(acc.y - acc.lastY, acc.x - acc.lastX) + PI/16;
```

Comment: Thank you Jan. I don't understand this part can you kindly explain little more about this part.  </br> "It's all the more tricky because of how you need the rounding to work. If you want some value to mean "about 0" in 0-360 range, you will need 355 and 5 return the same value, so you'll have to add the half interval, modulo 360 to get say 362 back to 2 and than divide."

Comment: @Prasad: I tried to describe rounding. Normally the rounding is towards zero, so 0 will cover direction along _x_ axis and slightly off towards positive _y_ only and directions along _x_ axis with even very small negative _y_ will yield 15. If you want direction along _x_ axis to be in the middle of range represented as 0, you'll have to add rounding.